# const qualifier for nested template functions in c++

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I want a template function **bar** to call a template function **foo** with **const** qualifier.

I have two templates for functions **foo** and **bar** with their instantiations. This is *foo.cpp*

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void foo(const T x){
    std::cout<<x[0]<<std::endl;
};
// instantiation here, in order to avoid implementation in header
template void foo<const int*>(const int*);
```

*foo.h*:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T x);
```

*bar.cpp*:

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void bar(T x){
    foo<const T>(x);
};
// instantiation here, in order to avoid implementation in header
template void bar<int*>(int*);
```

and *bar.h*:

```
template <class T>
void bar(T x);
```

finally, *main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
    int p[5];
    p[0]=17;
    foo(p);
    bar(p);
    return 0;
}
```

All .h files contain #ifndef/#define standard statements. Function **foo** is supposed to get an array of **int**s, and not to change it, therefore it has **const** qualifier in it. I want the function **bar** to receive an array of **int**s and change it, while at some point it should call function **foo** also. The reason for template use is that in the future I want to call these functions for different types of data, such as **double***, **std::vector< int >&**, etc.

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `void foo<int* const>(int* const)'
```

as if it cannot cast **int*** to **const int***. Also, it seems to replace pointer to const int to const pointer to int. Any idea how I can deal with it?

One more observation: if I remove *foo.cpp* and *bar.cpp* and instead merge everything in one file it compiles normally.

===================================

**Case solved**

Instantiation for **foo** is done for **< const int* >**. As people noticed, when **foo** is called in **bar**, **const T** casted to **T const == int * const** that is not the same as **const int***.

In order to turn it to **int const***, I added to the code:

```
typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type tmp_type; // tmp_type = int
foo<tmp_type const *>(x);
```

You need -std=c++11 to compile that. Alternatively, as Davis Herring proposed, you can use

```
foo<const std::remove_pointer_t<T>*>(x);
```

instead, but you will need to use -std=c++14 for this.

The problem had nothing to do with implementation of templates in header file, except for the obvious observation that none of that is needed if everything is in one file.

The other solution is to have two instantiations for foo:

```
template void foo<int const *>(int const *);
template void foo<int *>(int *);
```

where the first one does not let you change the value of the pointer inside the function, while the second one lets you pass just simple **int*** in it.

Comment: please most the full code you need to produce your error message.

Comment: "This is foo.cpp" I can already tell you that if that is your foo.cpp, that's not gonna work without reading the rest of the question. See [why templates must be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). This will cause an undefined reference since, as the linked question states, templates must be defined in the header.

Comment: "undefined reference to `void foo<int* const>(int* const)'" Sure enough, that error is probably because of the reason I mentioned, just a hunch.

Comment: @Chipster The OP is using explicit instantiation; they're just not doing it quite right. Maybe you should have read the rest of the question :) Also the rest of the question you linked to, because "templates must be defined in the header" is _not true_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Never mind. I read further into the FAQ. I got you now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Not quite a dupe (though reading that page wouldn't hurt); there's a good and actually interesting answer to this question, I just don't have time to write it right now.

Comment: @Chipster If I remove all const qualifier the code compiles and runs well. The problem arises only if I try to add const and to call foo from bar. If I add const and call foo from main it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `T` is `int*`, `const T` is `int *const`, not `const int*`.  (After all, given

```
typedef const T cT;
cT t1=/*…*/,t2=/*…*/;
```

it’s `t1=t2` that’s forbidden, not `*t1=*t2`.)

You can use `const std::remove_pointer_t<T>*` to construct `const int*` from `int*`.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this: foo<const std::remove_pointer<T>*>(x); but the error now: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(int*&)'

Comment: When I use foo<const std::remove_pointer_t<T>*>(x); I get the following error: error: parse error in template argument list      foo<const std::remove_pointer_t<T>*>(x);

Comment: @Vasily: Are you using at least C++14, with the right header?

Comment: -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++14 -g -std=c++11                                                                                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606445/c-compilation-error-remove-pointert-for-template-type

Comment: I finally made it work like the following. typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type tmp_tpe; foo<tmp_type const *>(x);

Comment: @Vasily: Why use `-std=c++14` **and** `-std=c++11`?

Comment: It is just what CodeBlocks for Windows has. I tried with g++ -std=c++14 for UNIX and it actually compiled fine.

Comment: @Vasily: Surely you can change that—passing both is nonsense and is why your attempt with `remove_pointer_t` (not `::type`) failed.